# Excel VBA: Easy If function doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: vba, excel

here's the code which I check for before executing an UserForm:

```
If Sheets("Warehouse").Cells(ProdID + 1, 3) < SalesQ.Text Then
    MsgBox ("Not enough quantity - ID: ") & ProdID.Text
    Exit Sub
End If
```

(If it succeeds, the Q is deducted from the sheet.)

```
Sheets("Warehouse").Cells(ProdID + 1, 3) = Sheets("Warehouse").Cells(ProdID + 1, 3) - SalesQ.Text
```

Basically I have 2 sheets - Warehouse and Sales, I insert data in Warehouse sheet with a userform code which is smth like (if you need more, let me know):

```
Cells(emptyRow, 1) = IDBox.Text
Cells(emptyRow, 2) = prodBox.Text
Cells(emptyRow, 3) = QBox.Text
```

So the issue is, after I have FIRST inserted the data in Warehouse sheet. Whenever I test out the selling in Sales part, it tells me Not enough quantity even though there is quantity. Now let's say the Q = 100, the Sales userform won't work if I enter 90, 80, 60, etc. but will work if I enter some small number like 20 or 10... After the initial deduction with small number like 10 or 20, it will work perfectly with any other number like 80 etc. I assume it's something with the endings like (.Text, .Value etc? but IDK) Halp.

Comment: I don't know what SalesQ is defined as. Assuming it's a range (i.e. a cell) then it should be `SalesQ.Value`. If it really doesn't contain a number, but does contain text, then instead of a boolean comparison (`<`) you will need to do a string operation.

Comment: What is ProdID defined as? It is used as an integer or long type in the IF statement, but then looks like it's used as a range in the MsgBox statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that SalesQ.Text is a text field of type String. Therefore you are comparing a number to s string - which is legal but may give unexpected results.

If SalesQ.Text really does contain a string which represents a number (e.g. it contains "120") then you can convert it to a number using the Val function

```
Sheets("Warehouse").Cells(ProdID + 1, 3) < Val(SalesQ.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) property of something is not going to compare mathematically against the [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or 
[Range.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) property without conversion to a true number.

```
If CDbl(Sheets("Warehouse").Cells(ProdID + 1, 3).Value2) < CDbl(SalesQ.Text) Then
    MsgBox ("Not enough quantity - ID: ") & ProdID.Text
    Exit Sub
End If
```

In short, `1` does not equal `"1"`.